# How to implement e-mail verification on sign-up, but not for social accounts in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am using Django-allauth for my authentication purposes. I currently have these settings:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED=True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = ("mandatory")

EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'me@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'
```

This works nicely. However, I also give my users the option to use their social accounts (Facebook and Twitter) to login. If they are logging in for the first time, then they are asked for an email and the system waits for verification. I do not want this. If the user logs in using a social account, he/she should not need to verify their emails.

So how can I change that? Once again, I do want an email verification, but **ONLY** if the user signs up using the sign up form, if they use a social account, they are directly logged in. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"

There is this setting available.